# Why include direct.h or sys/stat.h conditionally based on _WIN32 or __linux__?

Tags: c

What will the following code do? Why is it used?

```
  #ifdef _WIN32
  #include <direct.h>
  #elif defined __linux__
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #endif
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no portable way in C to manipulate file system directories. You need some library that provides wrapper interfaces to manipulate directories. (Using system call, OS interrupts routines etc)

`direct.h` is a header file for the C programming language for windows. It contains declaration of functions and required macros, struct etc used to manipulate file system directories. In Linux like system, you can use `sys/stat.h` for the same.

Now if your code may be compiled for either of the OS, you can keep the common (portable) code without any guards and keep windows-specific or linux-specific code in [conditional compilation](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap3/subsection2.1.3.4.html) block.

If you don't include those files conditionally, you may get `direct.h not found` or similar error in Linux and any similar error for windows.

`__linux__` is pre-defined by the compiler targeting the code for Linux.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) msdn document says:

> _WIN32: Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.

Answer (score 4):

This is a conditional statement but for **compilation time**.
When the program is compiled, it looks for the platform it is running on and includes the proper header for your OS (these libraries are implemented for a specific OS):

- `direct.h` for windows
- `sys/stat.h` for GNU/Linux

It works just like a classical `if/else` statement:

```
if(platform == windows)
{
    take_windows_lib();
}
else if (platform == linux)
{
    take_linux_lib();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It determines what library to include

So if you're running the code on a Win32 platform, it uses the direct.h library.

else if detects that it's running in a Linux platform, uses sys/stat.h library

Library availability different from platform to platform, and may not be available there.
I tend to prefer to ignore those libraries where possible. ie. conio.h is only available on old MS DOS input environments and will not work in a Linux/GNU environment

Comment: I'd think twice about that "standard" up there ;)

Comment: Actually, it determines which header file to include, which is a completely independent step from linking to libraries.